# Class Diagram , composition relationship

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have three classes:

-User class

-Role class

-UserRole class : to join both classes

Each user can have multiple roles.

So, I made this class diagram:

[image: Class Diagram]

Is the composition relationship between classes and the cardinalities correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When the relationship goes away, you don't want the other things to get deleted. The pointy ends must also be 1's.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely omit the composition diamonds as they add no real semantic to the model. Compositions are used on a metaphoric level and are more food for philosophers than anyone else.

Now for the multiplicities. A UserRole binds exactly one user to one role. You can have multiple UserRoles to reflect different roles for single or multiple users. So you should place a `1` to the left and right multiplicities.